# Maths: Find permutation number using one stack

Tags: function, numbers, stack, discrete-mathematics, catalan

*It's more a math problem I guess, nothing programming.*

Suppose I have a `stack` and I want to find the `permutations` of numbers `1,2,3,...n`.
I can `push` and `pop`.
e.g. if n=2: `push,pop,push,pop` 1,2 and `push,push,pop,pop` 2,1

if n=4 I can only get `14` from the `24` permutations using the `stack`..
Does anyone know any `function F(n)` that could produce the number of `permutations` the stack (only one) can produce? eg 
f(1)=1

f(2)=2

f(4)=14

Answer (score 3):

Such function is a Catalan number. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number for the formula.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Didn't know about those, but looking at the "Applications in combinatorics" section, this is exactly what we want here.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some quite easy formula for that. You're looking for permutations of `N` push operations ("X") and `N` pop ("Y") operations, following one simple rule:

- No pop on an empty stack (f.e. Y.... and XXYYY... are invalid)

Perhaps some recursive definition helps:

```
function F(n_push, n_pop) {
  int total_count = 0;

  if (n_push > 0) total_count += F(n_push - 1, n_pop);
  if (n_pop > n_push) total_count += F(n_push, n_pop - 1);

  return total_count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Very nice. I was looking something more close to mathematical terms though. I really appreciate for helping.